# I use microsoft word for my IDE, can I automate syntax highlighting as its taking me ages to do it manually for each line

Tags: syntax, ide, syntax-highlighting, highlight

As it says in the title. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have been looking around on forums and boards online but it is still escaping me. Possibly due to my unique choice of IDE. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Calling a word processor an IDE doesn't make it one.  Why not use an actual IDE?  Or even a simple text editor that has syntax highlighting?